# how to decrease the values ​of array1 in relation to array2 in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function to compare two arrays by position [2] of each array and make one array minus the other, but I'm having a problem with the final result, which should be:

```js
var ar1 = [['x123', '10', 'AA'],['x123', '20', 'BB'],['x123', '30', 'CC']]
var ar2 = [['x123', '12', 'CC'],['x123', '2', 'B1'],['x123', '2', 'CC'], ['x123', '2', 'BB']]

 var t = ar1.map(a => {
     var x = ar2.filter( b => b[2] == a[2])
     if( x.length > 0 ){
         return [a[0], a[1] - x[0][1], a[2]]
     } else {
         return a
     }

 })

console.log(t)
```

//the end result I would like

```
 ['x123', 8, 'B1']
 ['x123', 18, 'BB']
 ['x123', 6, 'CC']
```

Comment: you are getting 2 arrays in the filter when CC but you are only deducting only the 1st filtered element

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to subtract from what. `ar1` has inner arrays with a/b/c at element 0, and the end result you would like has the same structure. Which elements of arr2 are you subtracting to get that desired result (e.g. A1, 10 has no obvious element to subtract as it is the only 'a', and yet you want A,8 to be the output, where did the 2 subtracted come from?). A clearer explanation might help.

Comment: @DavePritlove they're trying to subtract the sum of the values in the second array in position 1 as filtered by the value in position 2 from their counterpart in the first array

Comment: @DavePritlove I adjusted the example of the question, but to do the subtraction I always use the position [x][2] of each array

in array1 will be a unique code

and in array2 it can be repeat or not appear as is the case with AA

Comment: @Fragosojp since x can be an array with more than 1 elements. do an x.forEach and deduct each element

Comment: `var g =a[1];
     x.forEach(e => {
      g = g- e[1]
     })      
     return [a[0], g, a[2]]`

Comment: @Fragosojp thanks for the attempt but it makes little sense to me. There is no B1 in the first array but it appears in the result with 2 next to it. What was subtracted to get 2 and why? Also 30,CC becomes 6,CC with 12,CC and 2,CC in array 2, neither of which alone or together subtract to give 6. What are the rules?

Comment: @cmgchess , perfect, it was what was missing and I couldn't see it, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, although your example and expected output don't quite match:

```js
const ar1 = [['x123', '10', 'AA'],['x123', '20', 'BB'],['x123', '30', 'CC']];
const ar2 = [['x123', '12', 'CC'],['x123', '2', 'B1'],['x123', '2', 'CC'], ['x123', '2', 'BB']];

 const t = ar1.map(a => {
     const x = ar2.filter(b => b[2] == a[2]);
     if (x.length > 0){
        const sum = x.reduce((prev, cur) => prev + Number(cur[1]), 0);
        return [a[0], a[1] - sum, a[2]];
     } else {
        return a;
     }
 })

console.log(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

too much code here but i got the same result

```js
/*  
var ar1 = [['A', '10', 'B1'],['B', '20', 'BB'],['C', '20', 'CC']]
var ar2 = [['C', '12', 'CC'],['B', '2', 'B1'],['C', '2', 'CC'], ['B', '2', 'BB']]
*/
var ar1 = [['x123', '10', 'AA'],['x123', '20', 'BB'],['x123', '30', 'CC']];
var ar2 = [['x123', '12', 'CC'],['x123', '2', 'B1'],['x123', '2', 'CC'], ['x123', '2', 'BB']];


//PREPARE ar2 :

tmp=[];
ar2.map(a2 => {

    ch=a2[0]+a2[2];//VIRTUAL KEY    
    vl=parseInt(a2[1]);

    /*
    if(tmp[ch]===undefined){
        
        tmp[ch]=vl;
        
    }else{
        
        tmp[ch]=tmp[ch]+vl;
        
    }*/
    tmp[ch]=(tmp[ch]===undefined?vl:tmp[ch]+vl);

});

solution=[];
ar1.map(a1 => {
    ch=a1[0]+a1[2];//VIRTUAL target KEY
    solution.push([a1[0],a1[1]-(tmp[ch]!==undefined?tmp[ch]:0),a1[2] ]);

});





console.log(solution);
```